# SharePoint Hosted App duplicate calendar issue

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

We developed SharePoint  Hosted App and released 1.0.0.0 version for first time into App Store.
Later with some Enhancements we released 1.2.0.0 version and published into App Store the problem is when customer upgrades to new version of my App Calender and Tiles List Appears Twice like below images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't say much with just the screen, but based on your description I assume there is some code/feature that adds the parts and get executed twice.